# How to call renderedCallback() in HandleChange field input only once

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-events, lwc-dom

I have LWC with search input, with every `handleKeyChange` click on input, `renderedCallback()` is called, but I need it to call only once.

Controller:

```
 @track hasRendered = false;
 @wire(getAcc, { searchKey: '$searchKey', fields }) wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {

        if (data) {

            this.items = data; 
            hasRendered = false;
            this.error = undefined;


        } else if (error) {
            hasRendered=false;
            this.error = error;
            this.data = undefined;

        }
    }
    handleKeyChange(event) {
            if (this.searchKey !== event.target.value) {
    
                this.searchKey = event.target.value;
                this.hasRendered = true;
                return refreshApex(this.data);
    
            }
        }
    
        renderedCallback() {
    
    
            if (this.hasRendered && sections.length != 0) {
                return;
            }
    
            let sections = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-accordion-section')
            this.hasRendered = true;
    
    
            sections.forEach((currentValue, index, array) => {
                currentValue.label = currentValue.name + " " + currentValue.label + "$"
    
            })
    
        }
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input type="search" onchange={handleKeyChange} class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12 slds-m-bottom--medium" label="Search"
                value={searchKey}></lightning-input>
                <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open class={multiple}>
                    <template if:true={items}>
                        <template for:each={items} for:item="acc">
                            <lightning-accordion-section key={acc.Id} name={acc.Name} label={concatenatedFields}>
                                <lightning-card  >
                                   <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
                                  /*here datas columns */
              </template>
         </template>
     </tbody>
</table>

</lightning-card>
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! This appears to be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) for which we don't have enough information to answer. There's probably a better solution to your underlying problem (X) rather than the solution you're aiming for (Y). If you don't mind, I'd ask that you take a moment to read [ask] and take our quick [tour], then come back and [edit] your question such that we have more information on what you're trying to do.

Comment: can you paste your HTML code .

Comment: <template>
    <lightning-card>
                <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open class={multiple}>
                    <template if:true={data}>
                        <template for:each={data} for:item="acc">
                            <lightning-accordion-section key={acc.Id} name={acc.Name} label={concatenatedFields}>
                                <lightning-card  >...

Comment: Please use [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/400787/edit) and add complete html template.

Comment: Have already add html code